# Programmaticaly Search and Download Application form AppStore with C#

Tags: c#, app-store, itunes, mac-app-store

I am working on an Windows application which need to programmaticaly connect to AppStore Search For an application and download the ipa for later use.

Is there any implementation of AppStore Protocol or an API,or at least specification of AppStore protocol?

Googleing don't give me any usefull result.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't think you can download the ipa's directly

Comment: But can i download at least something ? that i can later find out how to package as ipa

Comment: No I'm sorry I don't think you can. It's not my forte but I believe it would be a security risk if they did allow that

Comment: Not clear why it would be security risk? Seems that can't harm anyhow and is completely legal.

Comment: Downloading apps can trigger purchases tied to a user's credit card.  Thus no exposed public protocol.